# Получить количество подписчиков страницы в facebook

Tags: php, facebook-api

Пытаюсь получить количество подписчиков страницы тамким способом...

```
 public function getSubFb( $echo = false)
{
    $page_id = ' ';
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=" . $page_id . "") or die ("a lot");
    $likes = $xml->page->fan_count;
    if ($echo == true) {
        echo $likes;
    } else {
        return $likes;
    }
}
```

Не получается. Подскажите как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь всё написано в принципе:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group

Надо поставить PHP SDK фейсбука

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{group-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```